# Does JSON.stringify() always ignore methods when parsing objects?

Tags: javascript, json

I found the following in the [Mozilla-documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> If undefined, a function, or an XML value is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).

My question is: Do all modern browsers behave in this way? Can I rely on stringify() to ignore my object methods?

Comment: Firefox offers a propriatary method `.toSource()` for all of its objects.  While I'd not use it for anything more than testing and debugging, it can be amazingly useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The complete algorithm for `JSON.stringify` can be found in the specification: https://es5.github.io/x15.12.html#x15.12.3.

Basically, for every value that is not an object, `null`, a boolean, a number or a string, the serialisation function returns `undefined` and `undefined` values are not rendered.

That does not necessarily guarantee that every browser implements it this way, but the only browser getting out of line is normally IE. Every other browser is very close to the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Except for IE7, which doesn't implement it, and IE8, which requires document to be in standards mode, stringify works well across browsers

See:
http://caniuse.com/#search=json